# Picture box not working and setting it to another one

Tags: vb.net

I have two picture box one for photo and the other for signature but I notice when updating my information once I browse to change the signature it will automatically set the image to the same thing with the  one in photo

```
Public sub GetAccountSignsture(byval accountnumber as string, byval imageviewer as picturebox)

Connect 
Conn.changedatabase(“Bgsale”)
Cmd.commandtext=“select signature from tblaccounts where accountnumber =@id”
With cmd.parameters
.clear
.addwithvalue(“@id”,accountnumber “)
End with 
Dim rd as sqldatareader = cmd.executereader
If rd.hasrows then 
Rd.read
Dim imgstream as new system.io.memorystream
Dim imgbyte as byte()
Imgbyte= rd(“signature”)
For each img as byte In imgbyte 
Imgstream.write(img)
Next 
Image viewer.image.fromstream(imgstream)
Rd.close
Else
Rd.close
Image viewer.image=nothing
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I just displayed my code

Comment: That code is poorly formatted, and a variable name can't have a space in it.  If you want help, you will have to do your part and present readable code.  Do favor copy and paste versus typing the code.  Even with cleaned up code, I don't think we see enough to help with your issue.  Put Option Strict On at the top of your code file, and then fix all the errors you get from it.

Comment: That space was an error not on my code in vs it was when I was typing it on here I will show you how I called it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the PictureBox as a parameter, I have separated the database code from the user interface code.

The UI code gets the account number from a TextBox. I made a guess that it was and Integer in the database and used .TryParse to validate.

When you name a method GetSomething, one could assume that something will be returned. So, this is now a Function that returns an image.

Keep your database objects local to the method where they are used. This way you can be sure they are closed and disposed. A Using...End Using block will do this for you even if there is an error.

Try to use the .Add method on the parameters collection. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Since you are retrieving a single piece of data you can use .ExecuteScalar which will give your the value in the first column of the first row.

```
Private Sub DisplaySignatue()
    Dim acctNum As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, acctNum) Then
        PictureBox1.Image = GetAccountSignature(acctNum)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter AddressOf valid account number.")
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetAccountSignature(ByVal accountnumber As Integer) As Image
    Dim retVal As Object
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
         cmd As New SqlCommand(“select signature from tblaccounts where accountnumber =@id”)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = accountnumber
        cn.Open()
        retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    End Using
    Dim img As Image
    If retVal IsNot Nothing Then
        Using imgstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            Dim imgbyte = CType(retVal, Byte())
            imgstream.Write(imgbyte, 0, imgbyte.Length)
            img = Image.FromStream(imgstream)
        End Using
        Return img
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

**EDIT**

Let's check for Nothing before filling the PictureBox.

```
Private Sub DisplaySignatue()
    Dim acctNum As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, acctNum) Then
        Dim i As Image = GetAccountSignature(acctNum)
        If i Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("No signature retrieved")
        Else
            PictureBox1.Image = i
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter AddressOf valid account number.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That textbox is it necessary?

Comment: No, I was just using it as the source of the account number.

Comment: It’s saying arithmetic operations set to an overflow  I just called it this way picturebox.image =Accountsignature(cboAccountnumber.text)

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: If you send .Text when an Integer is expected then you may get unexpected results. What line does the error occur on?

Comment: When loading the signature to the picture box that’s when the error occurs